# Reference request: Symmetric Groups and linear control systems

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, control-theory, optimal-control

Just out of curiosity, I would like to know if Finite Symmetric Groups are related to control systems in some way. A quick google search did not reveal much. I am sorry if this is not a well structured question.

Comment: Not sure. But consider a discrete multi-variable control system where variables have symmetric such as an `electric 3-phase inverter` which converts DC to 3 phase AC and each phase at each moment is `1` or `0` (upper bridge transistor is ON or OFF).

Comment: This question is going to have to be way more specific before it can be answered. The best place to start with any sort of control theory is simply to pick a system (or class of systems) you are interested in controlling in some way. No doubt that group theory is likely to be relevant somewhere, but the best practice is to bootstrap from an actual system